# Zener Diode Circuit Sees Voltage without source applied

Tags: voltage, zener

I have a circuit into an optical isolator which is used to detect the status of a contact in the field.

[image]

Zener diodes are used in series to drop the voltage to the optical isolator as well as as series resistor to limit the current to about 3mA when the Zeners breakdown.

The puzzling phenomenon is that with field contract open in that there is no source voltage, one can read the sum of the Zener voltages at the input to the circuit.

Is it possible that the wire to the field contact provides enough "noise" so that it is possible to read a voltage at the input even though the contact is open and no source voltage is being applied?

Comment: A schematic would be useful to be clear on what you are doing here. Also, how exactly are you reading the Zener voltages?

Comment: Load meter with 1k then 100 k and observe voltages. Unloaded circuit will rectify mains pickup and will be limited by zeners. Can even get RF pikup in some cases.

Comment: I set up a Google Drive.  I hope this works. Here is the link:https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_O3P__R_R1DZi1vTE9RMnpEcHc

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I think your response is reasonable.  Can you take a quick look at the circuit that I posted to a share on Google Drive just to confirm your answer?  Thanks.

Comment: @HarrySnowden - something along the lines of what Russell mentions is almost happening - if you are reading voltage it's coming from *somehwere*, but more info is required to know whether it's conducted (e.g. a common impedance), near field capacitive/inductive coupling, or RF (far field eletromagnetic) The schematic is not very clear - for example it does not explain what the voltages shown are (measured? Sources) it needs the values of components added - between which two points are you measuring Von/Voff?. Are there any capacitors in your circuit?

Comment: Also, the wiring of your circuit and what is nearby is important, what type of cables you are using (shielded-how?/unshielded/etc)

Comment: @OliGlaser The source for "wetting" the field contact is sourced from two 48Vdc inverters with "auctioneering" diodes.  The measured voltage for the detection circuit is 46Vdc which can be explained by the forward voltage drop of the auctioneering diodes.  With the field contact open, the voltage at terminal "X" is 42Vdc which I think is the sum of the Zeners.  The Von and Voff voltages are just specifications for the DSI02 module so the Zener between the DSI02 and Terminal "X" is about 24V.  Switch S1 is in position C2.  Von and Voff would be between input of DSI01 and output (S1 common)

Comment: @OliGlaser -  The incoming cables shown by the dashed lines are unshielded and run about 30m from Terminal "X" to the field contact.

Comment: @OliGlaser - The values of the components are not available.  The modules NRDI03 and DSI02 are part of a distributed control system and the manuals do not provide the values so there is a bit of guess work here.

Comment: @OliGlaser - We did remove the contact and injected a voltage with respect to "-" with S1 set to C1.  We found that the circuit energized the optical input at around 42.6Vdc.

Comment: Just in case I confused anyone.  "inverters" should have read "converters".

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for their contributions.  I think it has confirmed my suspicions.  Unfortunately, I will not be able to do additional tests at this time as the circuit is not available while the plant is running.  I will write a report and suggest the additional testing at their first opportunity.  Happy New Year

Comment: @HarrySnowden - It does look like pickup from unintended coupling is at work. A resistor that loads down the circuit so stray input energy is absorbed should help - either from  X to S1 or across the DS102 if the external zener is too far away and would need too long a wire run. Resistor value = small enough to reduce voltage to an unimportant amount.

Answer (score 1):

We have seen long field wiring with water leakage and the circuit is no perfectly open circuit (4 V between poin + and X). Try putting a resistor, says 50k to 200k, Point X to point N/-.

Since 48V, you likely in telecommunication facility. If RF transmitter on site, it may explain the reading too.